# How to create animated countdown timer with progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer, progress-bar

I have this JS countdown timer but it doesn't work as I would like. I would need a normal time, for example 60 seconds. The green progress bar should move from left to right. When the remaining time is 10 seconds, the progress bar should turn yellow and when 5 seconds remains it should turn red. When the time is over it will remain red.

In a pinch, when it was 23 seconds, the progress bar will stop at this place.

```js
const FULL_DASH_ARRAY = 283;
const WARNING_THRESHOLD = 10;
const ALERT_THRESHOLD = 5;

const COLOR_CODES = {
  info: {
    color: "green"
  },
  warning: {
    color: "orange",
    threshold: WARNING_THRESHOLD
  },
  alert: {
    color: "red",
    threshold: ALERT_THRESHOLD
  }
};

const TIME_LIMIT = 20;
let timePassed = 0;
let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
let timerInterval = null;
let remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<div class="base-timer">
  <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="base-timer__circle">
      <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
      <path
        id="base-timer-path-remaining"
        stroke-dasharray="283"
        class="base-timer__path-remaining ${remainingPathColor}"
        d="
          M 50, 50
          m -45, 0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
        "
      ></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <span id="base-timer-label" class="base-timer__label">${formatTime(
    timeLeft
  )}</span>
</div>
`;

startTimer();

function onTimesUp() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
}

function startTimer() {
  timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
    timePassed = timePassed += 1;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
    document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
      timeLeft
    );
    setCircleDasharray();
    setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      onTimesUp();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }

  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

function setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft) {
  const {
    alert,
    warning,
    info
  } = COLOR_CODES;
  if (timeLeft <= alert.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(warning.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(alert.color);
  } else if (timeLeft <= warning.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(info.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(warning.color);
  }
}

function calculateTimeFraction() {
  const rawTimeFraction = timeLeft / TIME_LIMIT;
  return rawTimeFraction - (1 / TIME_LIMIT) * (1 - rawTimeFraction);
}

function setCircleDasharray() {
  const circleDasharray = `${(
    calculateTimeFraction() * FULL_DASH_ARRAY
  ).toFixed(0)} 283`;
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", circleDasharray);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  place-items: center;
}

.base-timer {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.base-timer__svg {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.base-timer__circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
}

.base-timer__path-elapsed {
  stroke-width: 7px;
  stroke: grey;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining {
  stroke-width: 7px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 1s linear all;
  fill-rule: nonzero;
  stroke: currentColor;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.green {
  color: rgb(65, 184, 131);
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.orange {
  color: orange;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.red {
  color: red;
}

.base-timer__label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Your code seems to already be working as you require...? Other than it's a circle, not a bar. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Yeah code working, but it's working, but i need bar. How to change code to bar?
I highlighted what I needed in the description.

I would need a normal time, for example 60 seconds. The green progress bar should move from left to right. When the remaining time is 10 seconds, the progress bar should turn yellow and when 5 seconds remains it should turn red. When the time is over it will remain red. In a pinch, when it was 23 seconds, the progress bar will stop at this place.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I would begin the approach of making a progress bar that is NOT a circle, and turns different colors on different thresholds.

First, I make a container for the time display, and the progress bar. Then I make a child to the progress bar container which is the actual progress. Then, I use js to update the css variable for progress, which is used to update the transform scaleX. The reason I use scaleX instead of width, is it is better for transitions and prevents reflowing the dom.

Then all that's left is to use some async magic in js which loops down every second, checking the progress to see if the color needs to be updated, and update the scale of the progress bar.

If you wanted a smoother transition of the progress bar you could instead make the transition for scale the length of the timer, however it would give you less granular control if your intention is to use the timer for a game or something. Also, this method opens the ability to pause, change times, and I just enjoy the aesthetic of ticking down instead of gradually decreasing. As if the game were on a 1 second interval update instead of continuous. It could be written either way for your intention though.

Hopefully this demo helps! If you have any other questions, feel free to ask.

I make use of css variables to hold my descriptive colors

```js
const get = query => document.querySelector(query);
const wait = s => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, s * 1000));

const display = get(".timer .display");
const progress = get(".timer .progress");

const WARN_THRESHOLD = .4;
const DANGER_THRESHOLD = .2;

const INIT_TIME = 15;
let timeRemaining = INIT_TIME;



(async () => {
  while (timeRemaining > 0) {
    timeRemaining--;
    display.innerText = `${timeRemaining}s`;
    const newProgress = timeRemaining / INIT_TIME;
    progress.style.setProperty("--progress", newProgress);
    if (newProgress > WARN_THRESHOLD) {
      progress.style.setProperty("--color", "var(--safe)");
    } else if (newProgress > DANGER_THRESHOLD) {
      progress.style.setProperty("--color", "var(--warn)");
    } else {
      progress.style.setProperty("--color", "var(--danger)");
    }
    await wait(1);
  }
})();
```

```css
/* CENTER TIMER */
.timer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* FLOW TIMER CONTENT */
.timer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  width: 200px;
}

.timer .progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  --height: 20px;
  height: var(--height);
}

:root {
  --safe: lightgreen;
  --warn: yellow;
  --danger: red;
}

.timer .progress {
  --color: var(--safe);
  --progress: 1;
  background-color: var(--color);
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--height);
  transform: scaleX(var(--progress));
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.1s, color 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer">
  <div class="display"></div>
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```